# How to compile the objective function in this optimization problem

Tags: optimization

For a series of variables, I have got the constrain functions:
$ax_{1}+bx_{2}+cx_{3}+dx_{4}=0$
$0 \le x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4} \le 1$

Now I want to find the solution that the minimum value of $x_{1},  x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4}$ is the greatest number in all solutions. For example, I have the following 4 solutions:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        x_{1} & x_{2} & x_{3} & x_{4} \\
        0.3 & 0.03 & 0.03 & 0.3 \\
        0.35 & 0 & 0 & 0.35 \\
        0.2 & 1 & 1 & 0.2 \\
        0.9 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

In all the above solutions, the third one is what I want to find. So how can I compile the objective function for such optimization problem? Thanks!

Comment: The word "compile" here in connection with "the objective function" is not a familiar verb.  Do you mean, how to express the objective?  You've described the objective as maximizing the minimum value of $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$, and so the expression is rather straightforward if you introduce a fifth variable to be an upper bound on these first four unknowns.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new variable $y$ and constraints $y \leq x_1,\ldots,x_4$, and maximize $y$.